# CSS: background-image not working properly

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am just starting out in the web development world so I am a beginner when it comes to html and css.

I am trying to create a background image for a paragraph of text on my web page but the image will not load for some reason.

**Image URL**
I am 100% sure I have the URL correct (the file is stored on a local directory) because using an image tag,

img src='C:/..../myimage.png'

works perfectly fine. Using background-image in CSS with this directory does not work though.

I am also trying out different IDEs to see which I like best. I started out using notepad++ and chrome browser. Using this, the background-image works fine. If I use Brackets, the background image does not show, even though it uses chrome as a live feedback tool.

Could someone please help me understand why this is not working?

Here is the html and css I have written. Thank you for any help you can give.

**HTML:**

```
<p id='bgimgex'>Here is a paragraph of text which has a background image</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#bgimgex{

    font-size:1.7em;
    color:cyan;
    margin:auto;
    width:50vw;
    background-position:center;
    background-image:url('C:/Users/Adad Dayos/Desktop/phase 2/course work/HTML series/HTML5_course_1/mod 5/images/melly.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Where is your CSS in relation to your HTML file?

Comment: Are you using a server like xampp or wamp, or are you opening the html file  from windows?

Comment: my html file location has 2 subdirectories, images and css. the images folder has images, and the css folder has my css file. This is why I had to use the full image directory in my css property, because the image was not in the same directory, or in a subdirectory of css.

Comment: I am not using any server. I am just editing my files locally using notepad++ and chrome, and trying to use brackets.

Comment: The css is in a different file, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply copy your image into your project directory and avoid using space (or ... ) in your sub-folder names .

if the problem still not solved please check your console in chrome (press F12) and see what is the error .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did check the console and found this:

"not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: @Adam: so the path is correct but your browser doesn't allow you to load resources due to CORS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the slashes "/" for "\\" because your css is in a separate file and it's being loaded from the browser.

```
background-image:url('C:\\Users\\Adad Dayos\\Desktop\\phase 2\\course work\\HTML series\\HTML5_course_1\\mod 5\\images\\melly.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working in all the browsers . I tested in my system. Please check in console (f12), if the browser is unable to load the background-image. I don't see any issues. Also please use file:///C:/Users for background-image

```
    <html>
        <style>
    #bgimgex{

        font-size:1.7em;
        color:cyan;
        margin:auto;
        width:50vw;
        background-position:center;
        background-image:url('file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg');
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }


    </style>

    <body>
    <p id='bgimgex'>Here is a paragraph of text which has a background image</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

**SOLUTION:**
Thank you to Parham Heidari for helping me solve this. I would upvote your answer but I am new to stack exchange and dont have the rep to do so.

So I checked the console in chrome using "inspect element" and saw:

[Console debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQP9.png)

This made me realize there was a security issue preventing the browser from retrieving my file. Apparently this happens when you provide a complete directory for a local file rather than a relative directory. So to fix the problem, I changed my url to:

```
background-image:url('../images/melly.PNG');
```

Also, thanks Andrei Gheorghiu for telling me how to fix the issue, even though I am pretty sure I just worked around it anyway.

Comment: "I don't have the rep to do so" doesn't apply to your own questions.  Since you are the question asker, you should be able to [(a) vote on answers to your question that you found useful, and (b) accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts).